# Symfony2 - The block type sonata.user.block.menu does not exist

Tags: symfony, composer-php, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

i have one exception:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The block type 
sonata.user.block.menu does not exist") in SonataUserBundle:Profile:action.html.twig at 
line 27.
```

I have intalled a FOSUserBundle + SonataAdminBundle , how i understand , i need tu install SonataBlockBundle and other required bundles.

My kernel file:

```
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new Ibw\JobeetBundle\IbwJobeetBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle(),
        new Sonata\CoreBundle\SonataCoreBundle(), 
        new FM\BbcodeBundle\FMBbcodeBundle(),
        new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
        new Sonata\jQueryBundle\SonatajQueryBundle(),
        new Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle(),
        new Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle(),
        new Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle(),
        new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle(),
        new Sonata\UserBundle\SonataUserBundle('FOSUserBundle'),
        new Sonata\EasyExtendsBundle\SonataEasyExtendsBundle(),
        new Application\Sonata\UserBundle\ApplicationSonataUserBundle(),
```

Adn my composer.json

```
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/data-fixtures": "dev-master",

    "sonata-project/core-bundle": "~2.2@dev",

    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "*",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "*",

    "helios-ag/fm-bbcode-bundle": "6.2",
    "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "@stable",

    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~1.3",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "*",
    "sonata-project/block-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sonata-project/cache": "1.*",
    "sonata-project/jquery-bundle": "1.8.*",
    "knplabs/knp-menu": "2.0.*@dev",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle":"dev-master"
```

All Bundle ar installed. So i have no idea why i have this error

app/config/config.yml

```
imports:
- { resource: parameters.yml }
- { resource: security.yml }

framework:
#esi:             ~
translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
secret:          "%secret%"
router:
    resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
    strict_requirements: ~
form:            ~
csrf_protection: ~
validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
templating:
    engines: ['twig']
    #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
default_locale:  "%locale%"
trusted_hosts:   ~
trusted_proxies: ~
session:
    # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
    handler_id:  ~
fragments:       ~
http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
use_controller: false
bundles:        [ ]
#java: /usr/bin/java
filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
    #closure:
    #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
    #yui_css:
    #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   "%database_driver%"
    host:     "%database_host%"
    port:     "%database_port%"
    dbname:   "%database_name%"
    user:     "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
    charset:  UTF8
    types:
        json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType
    # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
    # e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
    # path:     "%database_path%"



orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    auto_mapping: true


# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
parameters:
    max_jobs_on_homepage: 5
    max_jobs_on_category: 10
    max_blogs_on_page: 6

fm_bbcode:
  filter_sets:
    my_default_filter:
      locale: en
      xhtml: true
      filters: [ default ]

fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main

    user_class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
    group:
        group_class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group
    profile:  # Authentication Form
        form:
            type:               fos_user_profile
            handler:            fos_user.profile.form.handler.default
            name:               fos_user_profile_form
            validation_groups:  [Authentication] # Please note : this is not the default value       

sonata_user:
    security_acl:           false
    impersonating_route:    homepage # or any route you want to use
    class:
        user:               Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
        group:              Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group

    profile:  # Profile Form (firstname, lastname, etc ...)
        form:
            type:               sonata.user.profile
            handler:            sonata.user.profile.form.handler.default
            name:               sonata_user_profile_form
            validation_groups:  [Profile]

sonata_block:
    blocks:
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]

        sonata.block.service.text:
        sonata.block.service.action:
        sonata.block.service.rss:
        sonata.block.service.menu:
    default_contexts: [cms]

sonata_admin:
    title:      Admin Panel
    title_logo: /bundles/sonataadmin/logo_title.png
    templates:
        # default global templates
        layout:  SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig
        ajax:    SonataAdminBundle::ajax_layout.html.twig

        # default actions templates, should extend a global templates
        list:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list.html.twig
        show:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show.html.twig
        edit:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:edit.html.twig
    dashboard:
        blocks:
            # display a dashboard block
            - { position: right, type: sonata.admin.block.admin_list }

sonata_doctrine_orm_admin:
    # default value is null, so doctrine uses the value defined in the configuration
    entity_manager: ~

    templates:
        form:
            - SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle:Form:form_admin_fields.html.twig
        filter:
            - SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle:Form:filter_admin_fields.html.twig
        types:
            list:
                array:      SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_array.html.twig
                boolean:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_boolean.html.twig
                date:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_date.html.twig
                time:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_time.html.twig
                datetime:   SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_datetime.html.twig
                text:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
                trans:      SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_trans.html.twig
                string:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
                smallint:   SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
                bigint:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
                integer:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
                decimal:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
                identifier: SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig

            show:
                array:      SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show_array.html.twig
                boolean:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show_boolean.html.twig
                date:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show_date.html.twig
                time:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show_time.html.twig
                datetime:   SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show_datetime.html.twig
                text:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig
                trans:      SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show_trans.html.twig
                string:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig
                smallint:   SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig
                bigint:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig
                integer:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig
                decimal:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig
```

Comment: show your app/config/config.yml will be better

Comment: i edit question. config is there'

Comment: When do you have this exception ?

Comment: when i try to open /profile page.

Comment: I would try to update the packages with "php composer.phar update" to see if this solves anything but I can't really figure out without the code in front of me what could be the problem.

Answer (score 15):

I found this page

[How to add bundles in the Admin Dashboard Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250231/how-to-add-bundles-in-the-admin-dashboard-symfony2)

with this config in config.yml that works…

```
sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
         sonata.user.block.menu:    # used to display the menu in profile pages
         sonata.user.block.account: # used to display menu option (login option)
         sonata.block.service.text:
         sonata.block.service.rss:
```

Comment: I upload project in Bitbucket, maybe i share whith some one this project, and you try to help me?

Comment: I'm not sure to have enough time to help, but you can do it… if not me, maybe somebody else may help…

Answer (score 0):

Update this in your composer.json :-

```
        "sonata-project/user-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/datagrid-bundle": "dev-master",
```

Then in Config.yml update this :-

```
sonata_block:
default_contexts: [sonata_page_bundle]
blocks:
    sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
        contexts:   [admin]
    sonata.user.block.menu:
    sonata.block.service.text:
    sonata.block.service.rss:
```